# a question for the irreducibility test for degree 2 or 3 polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have a question for the irreducibility test for degree 2 or 3 polynomial. The test states: "Let F be a field, f(x) ∈ F[x], and degf(x) = 2 or 3. Then f(x) is reducible over F if and only if f(x) has a zero in F."

In the textbook, it states the test can be applied to polynomials in Z2[x] or Z3[x]. However, I don't think Z2 and Z3 are fields, just like Z is not field. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Wrong! Z2 and Z3 are fields, if this means $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, respectively $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Comment: For a prime $p,$ the ring $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ is a field. The reason there are multiplicative inverses: if $n$ is an integer not divisible by $p,$ there are integers $x,y$ such that $nx-py = 1,$ or $nx= 1+py,$ finally $nx \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Comment: I see! Thanks guys!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522921/the-ring-ℤ-nℤ-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-n-is-prime) about $\Bbb Z/n$.