# Explain why ($\mathbb{Z}_6$, +, · ) is not a field, where + is addition modulo 6 and · is multiplication modulo 6.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

Explain why ($\mathbb{Z}_6$, +, · ) is not a field, where + is addition modulo 6 and · is multiplication modulo 6.

When I was trying to explain why this is not a field, I came into a bit of trouble. I understand that for it to be a field the following must be true: Closure, Associative law, Identity and inverses. I wasn't sure how to disprove this. So far, Ive drawn a caylee table, but I havent been able to figure out what section disproves it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Think about which elements may or may not have multiplicative inverses here

Answer (score 2):

$2$ and $3$ do not have inverses and are zero divisors as $2 \times 3 = 6 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
What is the multiplicative inverse of $2$? That is, which number $x$ satisfies the property $2\cdot x=1$ in $\mathbb Z_6$?

Answer (score 1):

A ring R is a field if for every r in R, there exists s in R such that sr=rs=1(identity),
i.e. every element has multiplicative inverse.

In Z[6], 2 and 3 do not have inverse, thus Z[6] is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

As both 5xum and mathcounterexamples.net have pointed to, 2 is a zero divisor mod 6, and hence does not have a multiplicative inverse.

A more general observation is that $$\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$$ is a field if and only if $n$ is a prime power. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522921/the-ring-%E2%84%A4-n%E2%84%A4-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-n-is-prime) for answer to how to prove this.